# How to install gbarcode gem to Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I've problem with gbarcode gem which has dependency gnu-barcode c application.

When trying to say `gem install gbarcode` it says:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gbarcode-linux:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lbarcode... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I.  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c barcode_wrap.c
gcc -shared -o gbarcode.so barcode_wrap.o -L. -L/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib -Wl,-R/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib -L/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib -lruby -lbarcode  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libbarcode.a(library.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `encodings' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libbarcode.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gbarcode.so] Error 1
```

I've tried to install gnu-barcode application from ubuntu software center, apt-get and directly from source http://www.gnu.org/software/barcode/ and the response is always the same.

How should I install gnu barcode so that it's working with the gem.

And yes this project is quite heavy dependent on that gem so replacing it would be really painful to all parties.

Comment: I have no clue about `barcode` library, but the error states clearly: _recompile with -fPIC_. So I would suggest you to recompile barcode library with system-wide exported `export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC"` and then you gem should be successfully built.

Comment: Or even simplier, add `--enable-shared` when running barcode’s  `./configure` : `./configure --enable-shared`

Comment: See also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=708561, an updated version of the package for Ubuntu Trusty is available at https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/ubuntu/ppa